# Static page which uses Ajax to fetch "Latest posts" on homepage from Wordpress

Tags: seo, wordpress, ajax

I am making a website which has a blog as well as a "normal" website.

Would there be any negative consequences of installing Wordpress on a separate `blog.domain.com` and using AJAX to fetch information about latest posts from the WordPress site and loading this onto the regular html page? (I've not looked up the exact code which I'd need for this, but I'm pretty sure it's possible).

So basically, what I'd like to do is have two domains: `www.domain.com` which will consist of regular HTML pages, and a `blog.domain.com`. On the homepage of `domain.com` I want there to be a "Latest from blog" section, which I'd like to use AJAX to get the data for, as this is the only bit of the site which will change on a frequent basis.

Are there any disadvantages of this setup (SEO, etc.)?

/* Not really sure if this is the right SE site, but since it's basically "how to avoid using Wordpress" I feel like it's not right for the WP SE, and it's not really a programming question, so it doesn't belong on SO either lol. */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the technical end: you are not using Ajax to fetch the whole file, right?  You just want to create a job that extracts and uploads the latest blog post titles/links/[images](https://cloudinary.com/blog/file_upload_with_ajax) and maybe the meta description or first XX words. Do I have that correct? That is straightforward.

On the issue of a separate space for your blog: as long as your DNS records show that blog.domain.com is a subdomain of www.domain.com then they are linked for SEO and for search purposes. That would be preferred from an SEO perspective than using 2 separate domains.

On the blog: it sounds like you want to do a basic Wordpress install on a fresh environment and create a blog within that Wordpress site.  Correct?  That's simple enough. Make sure you have high quality content and complete all of the meta data for each post for higher scoring. For example, use good quality keywords (not too general, not crazy specific), put them in titles, slugs, meta descriptions and content -- good advice for both sides of your web presence.

As long as the two sites remain linked in your DNS and with references to each other, perhaps in the site map or about us page, then they should both have decent SEO scores. Just watch for any duplicate content so you do not incur penalties for that.